# Groovy regexp doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, groovy

Using groovy I want to match on the following: 
one word followed by a "." followed by a number.

```
assert 'randomword.[0-9]+' ==~ 'randomword.1'
assert 'randomword.[0-9]+' ==~ 'randomword.123'
assert 'randomword.[0-9]+' =~ 'randomword.1'
assert 'randomword.[0-9]+' =~ 'randomword.123'
assert 'randomword\\.[0-9]+' =~ 'randomword.1'
```

None of the above works, can someone explain me why and show me a way to do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
assert 'randomword.123' =~ /randomword\.[0-9]+/
```

Comment: So I messed up the sides .. Thanks for your answer.